# Use module of json web token in chrome extension

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension
I want use json web token node module of node.js but I get a error when I load the chrome extension.

**background-script.ts**

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

// import * as jwt from '../node_modules/jsonwebtoken';

const token = jwt.sign({
  number: 4,
  securityCode: 4,
  expirationDate: 1,
  name: 'christian',
  dniNumber: 13,
}, 'tokenSecret');
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

`node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js:1 (anonymous function)`

```
module.exports = {
  decode: require('./decode'),
  verify: require('./verify'),
  sign: require('./sign'),
  JsonWebTokenError: require('./lib/JsonWebTokenError'),
  NotBeforeError: require('./lib/NotBeforeError'),
  TokenExpiredError: require('./lib/TokenExpiredError'),
};
```

how should I import a node_module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solved this issue but it is necesary change the structure of project using webpack. so webpack compile the modules inside of class transpiled.

Comment: Having this exact issue. Mind sharing how you set up webpack?